# Getting totals from list of lists and apply it to a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list of lists such as this:

```
[['blah', 5], ['blah', 6], ['blah',7], ['foo', 5], ['foo', 7]]
```

What I want to do is create a list of dictionaries where the first index of the list is the key word and the second is the running total.

The end results needs to look something like this:

```
[{'name': 'blah', 'total': 18}, {'name': 'foo', 'total': 12}]
```

Comment: Have you attempted coding this yet? Can you show your attempt and explain what is not working out for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a Counter here:

```
from collections import Counter

res = Counter()
for k, v in data:
    res.update({k: v})

print(res)
```

output:

```
Counter({'blah': 18, 'foo': 12})
```

But if you really want the output you asked for:

```
final = [{'name': k, 'total': v} for k, v in res.items()]
print(final)
```

output:

```
[{'total': 18, 'name': 'blah'}, {'total': 12, 'name': 'foo'}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I honestly never thought about using collections, which was stupid of me.  Your answer was just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` to iterate over all elements and sum them up:

```
from functools import reduce

lists = [['blah',5],['blah',6],['blah',7],['foo',5],['foo',7]]

def count(total, item):
  key, val = item[0], item[1]
  if key not in total:
    total[key] = 0 
  total[key] += val 
  return total

totals = reduce(count, lists, {}) 
print(totals)
```